# How to create a 3x3 matrix and populate it with possibilities

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]
I want to create a python script that creates 3x3 matrix
And populate it with all the possibilities of having 3 squares populated at a time like in the image attached.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you think you should begin to approach this problem?

Comment: i'm thinking of numpy array but i don't know how to approach it

Comment: Broad sketch: write a function/generator that generates all possible lists of length 9, perhaps using `itertools.product`. Then write a function that turns lists of length 9 into 3x3 lists-of-lists. Then plug one into the other.

Comment: @Kevin Shouldn't that be `itertools.combinations`?

Comment: Oops, I misread the requirements. `product` would give you all possibilities of having any number of squares populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to approach this problem. As mentioned in the comments, what you're trying to do is get every combination of filling 3 of 9 empty buckets. Representing those buckets as a matrix afterwards is then just a matter of shuffling how the buckets are stored. You're right in that numpy will let you easily create matrices

```
from itertools import permutations
import numpy as np

# Gets all possible combinations of non-zero indices
non_zero_index_sets = permutations(range(9), 3)

# Turn these sets of 3 non-zero indices into length 9 vectors just containing
# zeros and ones, e.g. [2, 7, 8] becomes [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
vectors = []
for non_zero_set in non_zero_index_sets:
    vector = np.zeros(9)
    vector[list(non_zero_set)] = 1
    vectors.append(vector)

# Turn each length-nine vector into a 3x3 matrix, e.g.
# [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1] becomes [[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
matrices = [vector.reshape((3, 3)) for vector in vectors]
```

Here's a random output example:

```
ipdb> matrices[50]
array([[ 1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Check out the permutations documentation to see what it's doing in more detail. You can think about it as choosing 3 elements out of the list of possible indices that you want to be non-zero.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: I assumed the squares that were populated had to be adjacent. If that is not the case, then yes this would definitely be the correct answer.

Comment: @PrestonM no they don't have to be adjacent